# Short in central vacuum low voltage wiring

Tags: electrical, central-vacuum

I have a short in my home's central vacuum low voltage system but I'm having trouble finding it. Tested continuity at the powerhead and it's a closed circuit. Tested continuity at each wall plate and they're all open circuit except one of them. This is strange to me because they're wired in parallel, so a close at the powerhead should also be a close at all of the wall plates. I disconnected the wires from that wall plate anyway and there's still a close at the powerhead. Any ideas?

edit: powerhead is the wrong term here, I should've used 'unit'

Comment: How is the wiring of yours arranged? Are there (2) two-conductor cables at each of the inlet wall plates (except the last one) -- or is there just a single two-conductor cable at each? The latter implies that splices of the cable may be in concealed places and that the wiring can't be easily broken into segments which can be tested individually.

Comment: Marvin the mouse (or Ray the rat, or Sam the squirrel...) has been playing electrician for you, most likely.

Comment: @GregHill there are 2 two-conductor cables. One is 120V for brushhead power, the other is low-voltage for powerhead signaling, it's this one that's shorted somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

From the description: shorted between the powerhead and the plate reading closed, and disconnected between there and the other wall plates. Probably, but not definitely, the same location.

***Restating due to comment:*** Somewhere in the wiring that runs between the powerhead and the outlet that you read as closed, the wires to/from those end-points are touching each other (shorted together) so you read "closed" from those end-points. Since the other outlets read as "open" they must be not connected (on at least one side) to the wires that read as closed. Occam's Razor leans to both events being in the same place.

Depending how many "low voltage liberties" were taken in installing the wire, it may be difficult to get at the problem area, as some installers do things like bury splices and junctions in inaccessible areas. *We curse them roundly when we have to fix their work.*

Comment: sorry I'm not following your first paragraph, what do you mean?